# Rails Association Not Assigning Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Real story: I have models User, Profile and Hire.

A user has one profile. A user can hire any user for a job so that I can achieve this `User.first.hires`

```
#user.rb
has_one :profile
has_many :hires
before_create :build_profile
```

I need to know who a user hires so I set a foreign key (profile_id) as (user_id) is the current user. The Hire model looks like this, minus the timestamps:

```
#Hire Model
:id => integer, 
:user_:id => integer, #foreign key for user
:foo => :string,
:profile_id => :integer #foreign key for profile
```

Now to list all users who "John" hired:

```
h = User.first.hires
h.map do |p| p.profile_id end
```

My issue is, `profile_id` is not being assigned and I'm lost if it's because of the route or the associations. I can assign with no problem in rails_admin.

```
#profile.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :hires
```

**hire.rb:**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :profile
```

I have created a show page for a company `views/company/show.html.erb`. That page has a modal for the hire process. That modal comes from a render: `views/hires/_form.html.erb`. And in that form:

```
<%= form_for @hire, url: user_accounts_hires_path(current_user), :html => { :data => {:abide => ''}, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <h1>Hire Form</h1>
  <!--text fields and submit button-->
<% end %>
```

hires_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @hire = Hire.new
end

def show
  @hire = Hire.find( params[:id] )
end

def create
 employer = User.find( params[:user_id] )
 @hire = employer.hires.build(hire_params)

 if @hire.save
   #flash yes, no etc
 end
end

private
  def hire_params
    params.require(:hire).permit(:a, :b, :c)
  end
```

Recap:

Im on the company page. Press button for modal, fill out form, hit submit, all is well but `profile_id` is not being assigned. Only the `user_id`. Anything else you need to see?

**Answer for aliibrahim:**

Update create method:

```
...
employer = current_user
contractor_id = User.find( params[:user_id] ).profile.id

@hire = employer.hires.build(hire_params.merge({"profile_id" => contractor_id}))
...
```

And for the form (replace current_user with params[:id]):

```
<%= form_for @hire, url: user_accounts_hires_path(params[:id]), :html => { :data => {:abide => ''}, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Can you show your `build_profile` method?

Comment: what is the foreign_key from user to profile?

Comment: @aliibrahim I think that ships with rails 4+ :build_*

Comment: @Sravan that would be `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `def create` in the controller

```
def create
   employer = current_user
   contractor_id = User.find( params[:user_id] ).profile.id
   @hire = employer.hires.build(hire_params.merge({"profile_id" => contractor_id})    
 if @hire.save
   #flash yes, no etc
 end
end
```

Also your hire_params method should `permit` `profile_id`

Comment: Thanks. My url can be `/company/1` or `/company/2`. I need to grab the id in the params. Your answer grabbed the current_user id. So `employer.profile.id` would be the current user. I dont want that.

Comment: I  have not changed anything around `user_id` but just grabbing the `profile` for the employer object.

Comment: Maybe the modal is causing this. I'll see and report back

Comment: Without the modal, it's the same. It keeps finding "1" no matter if the url is at "2": `/company/2`. Although changing the ids show correct pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my edit so you can make changes to your answer for future reference. All mark this as the answer. Peace!